# Как найти в списке наиболее близкое значение Python?

Tags: python, list, datetime

Есть список -

```
a = ['2020-07-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-07-31', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-08', '2020-08-08']
```

И есть 2 переменные

```
b = '2020-07-27'

c = '2020-08-07'
```

Надо в переменную `b1` записать самое близкое значение к переменной `b` из списка,

то есть - `2020-07-30` либо `2020-08-08` не важно.

А в переменную `c1` записать самое близкое значение к переменной `c` из списка, то есть - `2020-08-06` либо `2020-08-08` не важно.

Comment: Минимальное: `b = min(a)`. Максимальное: `c = max(a)`

Comment: [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Поставьте галку слева от решивших вопрос ответов. У вас 9 вопросов и 0 принятых сейчас

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import date

a = [
    '2020-07-30',
    '2020-07-31',
    '2020-07-31',
    '2020-07-31',
    '2020-08-04',
    '2020-08-05',
    '2020-08-06',
    '2020-08-06',
    '2020-08-08',
    '2020-08-08'
]

b = '2020-07-27'
c = '2020-08-07'

a1 = [*map(date.fromisoformat, a)]

b1 = min(a1, key=lambda x: abs(x - date.fromisoformat(b)).days)
c1 = min(a1, key=lambda x: abs(x - date.fromisoformat(c)).days)

print(b1, c1)
# 2020-07-30 2020-08-06
```

**UPD**
Вариант с проверкой является ли строка датой

```
from datetime import date
from typing import List, Union


def check_date(date_val: str) -> Union[date, None]:
    try:
        return date.fromisoformat(date_val)
    except ValueError:
        return


def nearest_date(date_val: str, dates: List[str]) -> date:
    date_list: List[date] = [d for d in map(check_date, dates) if d]
    date_v = check_date(date_val)
    return min(date_list, key=lambda x: abs((date_v - x).days))


a = [
    '2020-07-30',
    '2020-07-31',
    '2020-07-31',
    '2020-07-31',
    '2020-08-04',
    '2020-08-05',
    '2020-08-06',
    '2020-08-06',
    '2020-08-08',
    '2020-08-08'
]

b = '2020-07-27'
c = '2020-08-07'

print(nearest_date(b, a), nearest_date(c, a))
```

Comment: Почемуто вылетает ошибка a1 = [*map(date.fromisoformat, a)]
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: ''

Comment: @pilityxxx https://repl.it/repls/DutifulFantasticWearable

Comment: @pilityxxx, потому, что в тех данных которые Вы используете попадаются даты не в том формате, который вы указали в задании или вообще не даты

Answer (score 3):

```
In [38]: import bisect

In [39]: import datetime

In [40]: a = ['2020-07-30', '2020-07-31', '2020-07-31', '2020-07-31', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2
    ...: 020-08-06', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-08', '2020-08-08']

In [41]: a = list(map(datetime.date.fromisoformat, a))

In [42]: a.sort()

In [43]: b = '2020-07-27'

In [44]: c = '2020-08-07'

In [45]: c1 = a[bisect.bisect_left(a, datetime.date.fromisoformat(c))]

In [46]: b1 = a[bisect.bisect_left(a, datetime.date.fromisoformat(b))]

In [47]: print(c1, b1)
2020-08-08 2020-07-30
```

`bisect` ищет подходящее место для `b` и `c` в `a` но чтобы при этом сохранился порядок `a`.

Comment: в американсклм стандарте даты как здесь написано нет необходимости конвертировать в datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что переменные `a`, `b`, `c` уже имеют присвоены значения (например такие, как в вашем вопросе).

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"          # год-месяц-день

a_dates = [datetime.strptime(d, fmt) for d in a]
b_date = datetime.strptime(b, fmt)
c_date = datetime.strptime(c, fmt)

b_diff = [abs(b_date - a) for a in a_dates]
c_diff = [abs(c_date - a) for a in a_dates]

b_min = min(zip(b_diff, a_dates))
c_min = min(zip(c_diff, a_dates))

b1 = b_min[1].strftime(fmt)
c1 = c_min[1].strftime(fmt)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Сначала всё переводим в формат `datetime.datetime` применением метода `.strptime()`.
2. Формат `datetime.datetime` уже позволяет сделать *разности между двумя датами* — сделаем их (в абсолютных значениях, в форме генераторов списка).
3. Вычислим минимальные значения разниц — но чтобы знать, к какой дате соответствуют очередная разница, сделаем это на **парах** `(разница, дата)`. (Пары получим применением стандартной функции `zip()`).
4. Из полученного минимального значения-пары вытащим второй элемент, т.е. дату (второй элемент имеет индекс `[1]`) и применением метода `.strftime()` конвертируем его обратно в строку.

Answer (score 0):

Да почему же все пытаются как-то усложниться, когда все на поверхности -  решение в **две строки:**

```
date = np.array(a, dtype=np.datetime64)
b1=a[np.argmin(np.abs(date-np.array(b,dtype=np.datetime64)))]
```

Пример(ы)  - привел на другом форуме.